# fwrite creates corrupt files

Tags: c, fwrite

Im having trouble with fwrite corrupting files.
The idea behind this program is to just create a RAW image file that exists out of pixels that I inserted into an array called Colors[]. Basically is should be making straight lines of the different colors im placing into the arrays. Now ive tried a whole lot of methods to write it into a file but if it hasnt been written out in bit mode it just doesnt work on my RAW image display program that I have created although other RAW images do work on it though.
Would there be any easier ways of doing exactly this that I want to do ?
There a version of this program where i use an array of chars to fill the buffer but its a whole lot more code. eX //unsigned char Col[] = {'f','f','f','f','f','f'};

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>



    char *readFile(char *fileName);

    int main()
    {
        unsigned int i;
        //Pixels in 24Bit mode
        unsigned int Colors[] = {0x00ff00,0x00ffff,0xffff00,0xffff00};
        FILE *fpw;
        fpw=fopen("MF.bin", "wb");

        /*A Buffer array for the pixels to be stored in before fwrite will be used to                
        dump the entire array to a file.
        640pixels by 480pixels * 3(each pixel has 3 ints)
        */
        unsigned int Buff[640*480*3];
        int y,z,CP=0;
        unsigned long x;
        for (y=0;y<=(480);y++)
        {
            if (x>=640)
            {

                CP = 0;
            }
            for(x=0;x<=640;x++)//3840);x++)
            {

                if ((x>=320))
                    {
                        CP = 1;
                    }


                    if ((x>=159) && (x<319))
                    {
                        CP = 1;
                    }
                    else if ((x>=319) && (x<439))
                    {
                        CP = 2;
                    }
                    else if ((x>=439) && (x<640))
                    {
                        CP = 0;
                    }

                    else if (x>=640)
                    {
                        CP =0;
                    }

                Buff[480*y + x] = Colors[CP];
                printf("%u--%u,%u\n",(480*y + x),Buff[480 + x], Colors[CP]);
            }

            unsigned int xx = fwrite(Buff, 1, sizeof(Buff)/sizeof(Buff[0]), fpw);
            printf("--&z--",xx);
        }
        fclose(fpw);
    }
```

Comment: When you say "corrupt", what specifically do you mean? Is the file of the correct size to begin with?

Comment: Well...neither Notepadd++ or Notepad wants to open it..both just crash...haha who would have though :/

Comment: Well, it's binary data, not sure you can expect either of the Notepad clones to make heads or tails of it.

Comment: Notepad++ is a good *text* editor, but it cannot read images. Nor would one expect it to.

Comment: Oh no I dont want it to open up an image with notepad++ but looking at the bits you can kind see what color its suppose to represent. So therefore I read it in Notepad++ BUT not even that can open it.

Comment: Better find yourself a good Hex viewer. (Can't recommend one for Windows as I always use my own, but `010 Editor` seems rather impressive. On my Mac I use `0xED`. Don't know of anything good for Linux.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes...

`Buff[480*y + x] = Colors[CP];`

should be

`Buff[640*y + x] = Colors[CP];`

and the `y` loop should be `< 480` not `<=`, same for x.

You are using unsigned ints so you don't need to multiply by 3 in your `new`.  Using fwrite to directly write out 24 bit data won't work like that, as you have an array of 32 bit data, and your calculation for how many bytes to write is incorrect (you need to multiply not divide, but as stated above that would also be wrong because you have 32 bit data instead of 24).

There's no 24 bit data type, so you should use an array of unsigned char not unsigned long and do each colour component individually.

Comment: I was afraid of doing that color components individually thats why I tried to wing it with int. 
Yes my Math is messed up cause I can barely see anything with flu...horrible day to code.
How would you recommend me doing the individual color components though?
       unsigned char ColArr[] = {ff,ee,dd,cc};

Comment: Yes I would recommend doing individual components using an array of unsigned char, you will find it much easier, and it will allow you to output it all at once using a single fwrite() call.  At the moment, you're using an unsigned int, so your data looks like 0x00bbggrr - you have 8 bits of zeros in the high bits, which you don't want to write to the file.

Comment: p.s. I also recommend going to bed and leaving the code until you feel better :P

Comment: hahah thanks MrZebra... Seems like you give good life advice also... stuck at work unfortunately.